# Marshmallow 6.0.1 onMessageReceived() called multiple times

Tags: android, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using Firebase push notifications. All other mobile devices show one notification but my Marshmallow 6.0.1 shows 40 to 50 notifications.
`google.message_id` is changed every time.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    // this method is called multiple times
}
```

Comment: Having same issue. onMessageReceived called every minute.

Answer (score 0):

update firebase in your project, it is solved my problem

Comment: please add it as a comment, not worthy to put it as an answer.

Comment: i dont have enough reputation for add comment, i can delete my answer

Comment: I am already using "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2".
But not working